# Style seach input with icon: keep input element at a size of its container and icon on same line

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I´m trying to build a search input with an icon on its side. I´m using ReactJs.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Icon } from 'react-fa';

import '../index.css';

class SearchInput extends Component {

    static propTypes = { 
      placeholder: PropTypes.string
    };


    render() {

            return (
                <div className='ux-search-input-container'>
                    <input className='ux-search-input' type='text' placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
                    <Icon className='ux-search-input-icon' name='search' />
                </div>
                );
    }
};

export default SearchInput;
```

And its styling:

```
.ux-search-input-container {
    color: $ux-color-text;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: $ux-color-border;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.ux-search-input {
    width: 70%;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; // top right bottom left
    border: none;
    border-width: 0px;
}

.ux-search-input-icon {
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;
}

.ux-search-input:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px $ux-color-light-blue;
    background-color: $ux-color-hover;
}
```

The search icon is moving to the next line, as:

[image]

I need to keep search icon in the size of the input box, not matter how small is the container. If the container shrinks or enlarges, the input box should follow the size and keep the search icon on its right size.

Comment: try adding `display: inline-block` to `ux-search-input-icon` class?

Comment: @canaan seaton: Not working. Same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach 1

Add `display: flex` to the `ux-search-input-container` class in your *CSS*.

Then add padding to center it.

#### Approach 2

Add `position: relative` to the `ux-search-input-container` class and then add `position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 5px` to the `ux-search-input-icon` class.

*Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cmseaton42/pen/YxVYJw) using second approach.*

Comment: Woking fine on 2nd approach. Thanks.

Comment: Happy coding =]